# Linux login via node.js

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, crypt, child-process

I'm currently building an (experimental) webapp to login and control a (linux) server (especially for monitoring) in node.js.
For authentification i would like to use the linux users.

Either via `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`, reading information works quite good, but i can not authenticate (`crypto`, `bcrypt` won't work), via `child_process.exec` i can execute `openssl passwd`, this only generates md5 (`1`), but the passwords stored in `/etc/shadow` are encrypted with SHA512 (`6`). Is there any way I'm missing out?

The other way i tried, is using the `login` command (via `child_process.spawn`). but this always exits with code `1`. All other commands (e.g. `apt-get upgrade`) work as expected.

PS: my server is running on `root` so there should be no problem with permissions.

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**:
As i already pointed out, this is an **EXPERIMENTAL** project, so I'm not planning to use it in production, i was just curious about it. It's a bit similar to [PCMonitor](https://www.mobilepcmonitor.com/)

I know running it as `root` is not a good idea, and thats not what i would use in production apps.

**To clarify**:
My question was more about, why every command (i have tried so far) works good with `child_process.spawn` except `login`. And how i could generate a `SHA512` password with a salt (exactly like the ones in `/etc/shadow`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If your server is running as root, you can just `su` to any user with no password. Are you saying you want users to use their linux passwords to authenticate with your server? That's almost certainly a bad idea. What are the clients running? Web pages?

Comment: I think running your web app as root is a bad idea at all!

Answer (score 1):

Well this question is rather old, but I stumbled upon a similar problem verifying the entered password against the systems user db. Maybe this can help others having the same task.

I finally did it via the [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) tool.
So I came up with this expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set username [lindex $argv 0];
set password [lindex $argv 1];
set timeout 5

puts "$username $password"

if {[file exists /usr/bin/su]} {
    spawn /usr/bin/su $username
}
if {[file exists /bin/su]} {
    spawn /bin/su $username
}

expect -exact "Password:"
send "$password\n" 

expect { 
    -ex "su: " {
        puts "login failed"
        exit 1
    }
    -ex "@" {
        puts "login successful"
        send "exit\n"
        exit 0
    }
    timeout {
        puts "login failed (timeout)"
        exit 1
    }

    default { 
        puts "login failed (unknown reason)"
        exit 1
    }
}
```

If you save this script for example as pw_check.sh you then can call it like this in nodejs

```
var child = execFile(
        '/path/to/pw_check.sh',
        [username,password],
        {stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe']});

        child.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
            if (code === 0) {
                //pw check was successful
            } else {
                console.log("Authentication error.")
                //pw check failed
            }
        });
```

I must admit that this is not a very secure way to do this, but I found no better one yet. And creating a separate user db was no option for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use node.js to connect via SSH to the localhost server, check out this module https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2 . You can forward the commands sent via the web api to the ssh connection.

This way it would be a lot safer than exec-ing commands, and you would be able to use any users allowed to ssh.

Comment: thanks, i've already seen this one, but i was more curious about, why `login` does not execute and if there is a way to copy the algorithm used in `/etc/shadow` (i've updated my question)